# Where is ZendX API reference?

Tags: zendx

Can someone point me to the official ZendX API reference ? The only official page I was able to find using Google is the Google Code project page which is pretty scarce...

Thanks by advance,

Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like there isn't official ZendX API reference. Moreover, ZendX's future doesn't look that good :

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Discontinuing-Maintenance-of-ZendX-JQuery-Suggest-drop-for-2-0-td3221855.html

So I guess this is not a big deal if the documentation is scarce...